# Intent равен null в Activity

Tags: android

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка.

Блок передачи:

```
public void ClickStart(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("fest_dig", fest_text.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("sec_dig", sec_text.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Блок приема:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fest = intent.getStringExtra("fest_dig");
    String sec = intent.getStringExtra("sec_dig");
    ...
}
```

Лог ошибки:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.trener_math/com.example.an‌​droid.trener_math.Ma‌​inActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String
>   android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference

Comment: В чем собственно ошибка? Приложение падает? Лог сообщения ошибки добавьте сюда. Или просто не корректные значения?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.trener_math/com.example.android.trener_math.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Приложение падает

Comment: Лог сообщения желательно добавить в тело вопроса

Comment: Укажите весь метод, где ваш "Блок приема" находится.

Comment: 'public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fest = intent.getStringExtra("fest_dig");
    String sec = intent.getStringExtra("sec_dig");'

Comment: Вы прямо при объявлении полей класса инициализацию делаете что ли? Конечно там интент null. Перенесите этот код в метод `onCreate()`.

Comment: Сделайте ответом. Помогло.

Comment: Автор, без знания жизненного цикла никак в нашем деле ;)

Comment: Первое приложение пишу)) Про жизненный цикл просто пролистал))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На базе комментария от [@eugeneek](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14141/eugeneek)

Перенесите код в активности-приемнике из обьявления полей в метод `onCreate`. Именно там доступен `Intent`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInsranceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fest = intent.getStringExtra("fest_dig");
    String sec = intent.getStringExtra("sec_dig");
}
```